# Save date and time picker data into Firebase Cloud Firestore database in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, save

I have implemented the Date and Time picker in my Flutter app. I want to save picked Date and Time into Firebase Cloud Firestore Database

```
RaisedButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            elevation: 4.0,
            onPressed: () {
              DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                  theme: DatePickerTheme(
                    containerHeight: 210.0,
                  ),
                  showTitleActions: true,
                  minTime: DateTime(2010, 1, 1),
                  maxTime: DateTime(2030, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
                print('confirm $date');
                _date = '${date.year} - ${date.month} - ${date.day}';
                setState(() {});
              }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
            },
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 50.0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.date_range,
                              size: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.teal,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              " $_date",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.teal,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "  Change",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            elevation: 4.0,
            onPressed: () {
              DatePicker.showTimePicker(context,
                  theme: DatePickerTheme(
                    containerHeight: 210.0,
                  ),
                  showTitleActions: true, onConfirm: (time) {
                print('confirm $time');
                _time = '${time.hour} : ${time.minute} : ${time.second}';
                setState(() {});
              }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 50.0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.access_time,
                              size: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.teal,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              " $_time",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.teal,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "  Change",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text(isEditMote ? "Update" : "Save"),
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                try {
                  if (isEditMote) {
                    Note note = Note(
                      appID: _appIDController.text,
                      doctorName: _doctorNameController.text,
                      healthIssue: _healthIssueController.text,
                      hospital: _hospitalController.text,
                      id: widget.note.id,
                    );
                    await FirestoreService().updateNote(note);
                  } else {
                    Note note = Note(
                      appID: _appIDController.text,
                      doctorName: _doctorNameController.text,
                      healthIssue: _healthIssueController.text,
                      hospital: _hospitalController.text,
                    );
                    await FirestoreService().addNote(note);
                  }
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

This is the relevant sample code. I passed 4 other parameters to database, like that I want to pass this Date and Time picker data. First two Raised Buttons contains the Date and Time picker, final raised Button regarding the Data Saving unit.

Comment: What's your question about all that code?

Answer (score 1):

You saved date time as integer value in Epoch time stamp or as a DateTime object.

```
int selectedDT=pickedDateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionName').document(docName).setData({
'date_time': selectedDT
 });
```

OR

```
DateTime selectedDT=pickedDateTime;
Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionName').document(docName).setData({
'date_time': selectedDT
 });
```